# SObjectCollection in Composite request limits

Tags: rest-api, sobject, composite

According to the [composite API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm) documentation,

"You can have up to 25 subrequests in a single call. Up to 5 of these subrequests can be query operations, including Query, QueryAll, and “Query More” requests to obtain the next batch of query results."

When I group together a bunch of [SObject Collection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections_retrieve.htm) calls, I seem to be limited to 5 calls per single composite request.

Why is that? SObjectCollection is not Query/QueryAll/QueryMore? Can I do something about this?

Comment: @identigral - as of Spring 22, [composite graphs don't support queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_graph_introduction.htm) AFAIK

Comment: @cropredy Yup - they never did, comment was incorrect and has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Composite it only allows you up to 5 subrequests of [sObject Collections](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections.htm) or query operations.

Each sObject Collections can have [up to 200 records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections_create.htm)

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm

EX.

```
{
"allOrNone": true,
"collateSubrequests": true,
"compositeRequest": [
    {
        "method": "POST",
        "referenceId": "refContact",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/Contact/",
        "body": {
            "lastname": "John Doe With Case",
            "Phone": "1234567890"
        }
    },
    {
        "method": "POST",
        "referenceId": "refAccount",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/Account/",
        "body": {
            "Name": "John Doe Account With Case"
        }
    },
    {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/Case/",
        "referenceId": "refParentCase",
        "body": {
            "Product__c": "GC1040",
            "AccountId": "@{refAccount.id}",
            "ContactId": "@{refContact.id}"
        }
    },
    {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/Case/",
        "referenceId": "refCase",
        "body": {
            "Product__c": "GC1040",
            "ParentId": "@{refParentCase.id}"
        }
    },
    {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/services/data/v50.0/composite/sobjects/",
        "referenceId": "refCaseSolution",
        "body": {
            "records": [
                {
                    "attributes": {
                        "type": "CaseComment"
                    },
                    "CommentBody": "example.com",
                    "ParentId": "@{refCase.id}"
                },
                {
                    "attributes": {
                        "type": "CaseComment"
                    },
                    "CommentBody": "Johnson",
                    "ParentId": "@{refCase.id}"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}